# Accesing information from a POST form in django 1.6

Tags: django, python-2.7, django-models, django-forms

I have a couple of forms, one is created from as a ModelForm and the other is a simple Form. Both of them are used in a request.POST, and to obtain the information from them I am using to different methods:

For the ModelForm form, I do this:

```
form = ApplicantForm(request.POST)
if form.is_valid():
    applicant = form.save(commit=False)
    applicant.confirmation_code = '999999'
    applicant.save()
```

For the simple form, I am using:

```
form = ConfirmationCode(request.POST)
code = request.POST['confirmation_code']
confirmation_id=request.POST['confirmation_id']
```

As you can see, to access the information in the first form I am using the "form.save.ANYFIELD", and for the second one I am using "request.POST['ANYFIELD']. Is it possible to access the the information in the first form using the request.POST methods even if it hasnt been saved? Which is better?

Comment: The form in the second example is doing *nothing at all*, and is completely pointless since you are accessing the POST data directly - you could do that without the form.

Comment: Now that you said it, I can notice its completely true!!! Thanks for pointing it out... Now, if I would need to access the information in the form variable, do I need to save it first? Is it possible to save a  simple form instance? (the form variable IS  a form simple form instance, right?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem a bit confused about what saving is doing in a modelform. When you call `form.save()`, you're creating a new instance of the model the form is associated with, and (unless you specify `commit=False`) saving that data to the database. Because you have an instance, you can use any of the normal model instance methods and access patterns.

If you want to use a form without an associated model, you can't call `save` - because there's nothing to save, and no model to create an instance of - but you should access the data via the `form.cleaned_data` dictionary after you call `form.is_valid()`. This is because the data in `cleaned_data` has been validated according to the rules in the form, and converted into the relevant types where necessary: for instance, if you had an IntegerField in your form called `my_number`, `request.POST['my_number']` will be a string like `"3"` but `form.cleaned_data['my_number']` will be an actual integer, `3`.

Comment: Thanks for the clear and developed explanation!! I really needed it.

Answer (score 2):

You can try like this for modelform:

```
form = ApplicantForm(request.POST)
if form.is_valid():
   app_code= form.cleaned_data['confirmation_code'] #assuming confirmation_code is a field in your modelform
   .....
```

Comment: Do you mean that I dont have to save the form instance to access its information? Why is this better than using the form.save().confirmation_code?

Comment: you don't need to save it to access data. you can access data by calling `form.cleaned_data['field_name']`